# Pluralisation bugs in /apps/oauth

Tags: bug, stackapps

In the [Manage your applications](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth) page, if 1 user has authorized and has been given an access token, the site shows 1 user**s** instead of user:

[image]

In addition, if you have one application, it shows 1 application**s**:

[image]